# The Exponent, Percentage, and Square Root Buttons on My JavaScript Calculator Won't Work

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I cannot get the exponent, percentage, neither the square root buttons on my JavaScript web app to work for the life of me! The editor isn't showing me any problems when analyzed, so I don't know what the problem is.Can you see where there could be errors in my code?

Here's my code pen:https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/zEBoOQ/

Here's the HTML code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ziontific Calculator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1 id="heading">ZIONTIFIC CALCULATOR</h1>
        <div class="form holder">
           <form id="formone" name="calc">
          <input id="display" type="text" name="display" placeholder=".....get on board...." disabled contenteditable="false" >

             <!--input type="text" placeholder="ExampleDomain"-->

          <br>
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="1" onClick="calc.display.value+=1">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="2" onClick="calc.display.value+=2">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="3" onClick="calc.display.value+=3">
          <input class="button three" type="button" value="C" onClick="Resetfunction(this.form)">
          <input class="button three" type="button" value="<-" onClick="backspace(this.form)">
          <input class="button three" type="button" value="=" onClick="evaluation(this.form)">

          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="4" onClick="calc.display.value+=4">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="5" onClick="calc.display.value+=5">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="6" onClick="calc.display.value+=6">
          <input class="button opps one" type="button" value="-" onClick="calc.display.value+='-'">
          <input class="button opps one" type="button" value="%" onClick="calc.display.value+='%'">
          <input class="button end one" type="button" value="cos" onClick="cos_function()">



          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="7" onClick="calc.display.value+=7">
          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="8" onClick="calc.display.value+=8">
          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="9" onClick="calc.display.value+=9">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="*" onClick="calc.display.value+='*'">
          <input class="button n" type="button" value="n!" onClick="fact_function()">
          <input class="button sin"type="button" value="sin" onClick="sin_function()">

          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="." onClick="calc.display.value+='.'">
          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="0" onClick="calc.display.value+=0">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="," onClick="calc.display.value+=','">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="+" onClick="calc.display.value+='+'">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="/" onClick="calc.display.value+='/'">
          <input class="button end two" type="button" value="tan" onClick="tan_function()">

          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="E" onClick="calc.display.value+=2.718">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="pi" onClick="calc.display.value+=3.141">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="x^y" onClick="power_function()">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="(" onClick="openpara(this.value)">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value=")" onClick="closepara(this.value)">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="log" onClick="log_function()">

          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="sqrt" onClick="sqrt_function()">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="LN2" onClick="calc.display.value+=0.693">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="LN10" onClick="calc.display.value+=2.302">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="log2E" onClick="calc.display.value+=1.442">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="log10E" onClick="calc.display.value+=0.434">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="EXP" onClick="exp_function">

          </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
body{
  text-align: center;
  background-color;
}


h1{
color: white;
}


    .container{
        background-image:   url(https://s26.postimg.org/frq6u3odl/texture-seamless-wood-3.jpg);
        position: relative;
        max-width: 550px;
    padding: 10px;
        height: auto;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        border: 0;
}
.form.holder{
  max-width:500px;
  height:auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  background-color:black;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:10px;
  border:2px groove #333;
  box-shadow:4px 4px 2px #666666;
  overflow: hidden;
}

 #formone{
    padding-top:35px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}  

input, textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}

input{
  display: inline
    font-size: 30px;
}

#display{ 
  height:60px;
  width:84.5%;
  color: blue;
  margin:3px;
  border:2px inset black;
  border-bottom:2px inset #FFF;
  border-right:2px inset #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color:#c6c6c4;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}


.button.end.one,.button.number.one,.button.three,.button.opps.one,.button.number.two,.button.opps.two,.button.n, .button.sin,.button.end.two,.button.third.row {
font-size: 20px;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 5px;
border: none;
color: white;
width:12.5%;
height:60px;
margin: 3px;
}


.button.end.one{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}


.button.number.one{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}


.button.three{
background-color: #4CAF50;
}


.button.opps.one{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  }


/*
.button.number.two{
  background-color: #ffff00;
}


.button.opps.two{
  background-color: #ffff00;
}

.button.n{
  background-color: #ffff00;
}

.button.sin{
  background-color: #ffff00;
}

.button.end.two{
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
*/


.button.end.two, .button.sin, .button.n, .button.opps.two, .button.number.two {
  background-color: #ffff00;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
}



.button.third.row{
  background-color: #ef1a07;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
 #heading{
  font-size: 20px !important;
 } 
} 


@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
 .button.end.one,.button.number.one,.button.three,.button.opps.one,.button.number.two,.button.opps.two,.button.n, .button.sin,.button.end.two,.button.third.row{
font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
 .button.end.one,.button.number.one,.button.three,.button.opps.one,.button.number.two,.button.opps.two,.button.n, .button.sin,.button.end.two,.button.third.row{
font-size: 9px;
  }
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {  .button.end.one,.button.number.one,.button.three,.button.opps.one,.button.number.two,.button.opps.two,.button.n, .button.sin,.button.end.two,.button.third.row{
  width:12%;
  height:50px;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 302px) {
   #heading{
  font-size: 15px !important;
 } 
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 302px) {
  .form.holder{
  height: 450px;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 302px) {  .button.end.one,.button.number.one,.button.three,.button.opps.one,.button.number.two,.button.opps.two,.button.n, .button.sin,.button.end.two,.button.third.row{
  width:12%;
  height:30px;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 302px) {
  .form.holder{
  height: 325px;
  }
}
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
flag = 0;

function openpara(val) {
    calc.display.value += val;
    flag += 1;
}

function closepara(valval) {
    calc.display.value += valval;
    flag -= 1;
}

function backspace(calc) {
    var size = calc.display.value.length;
    calc.display.value = calc.display.value.substring(0, size - 1);
}

function Resetfunction(calc) {
    calc.display.value = "";

    flag = 0;
}

function cos_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += Math.cos();
}

function sin_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += Math.sin();
}

function tan_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += Math.tan();
}

function log_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += Math.log();
}

function sqrt_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += Math.sqrt();
}

function exp_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += 'Math.exp(';
}

function fact(x) {
    factvar = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        factvar = factvar * i;
    }
    return factvar;
}

function fact_function(x) {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += 'fact(';
}

function power_function(x) {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += Math.pow(x,y);
}

function evaluation(calc) {
    n = calc.display.value;
    var size = calc.display.value.length;
    var lastchar = calc.display.value.charAt(size)
    if (isNaN(lastchar) && lastchar != ")" && lastchar != "!") {
        calc.display.value = "syntax error";
    } else if (flag != 0) {
        calc.display.value = "error:paranthesis";
    } else {
        result = eval(n);
        calc.display.value = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For you sqrt function, the value is missing :

```
function sqrt_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value = Math.sqrt(calc.display.value);
}
```

For the percentage, it is the modulo in javascript, and I tried 6%5 which gives 1 with your tool, that's good.
If you want the percent, you just have to divide by 100.

```
calc.display.value = calc.display.value / 100;
```

For you log, you concat the value, which is wrong I think :

```
calc.display.value+=1.442
```

For your exponent, the () are missing

```
<input class="button third row" type="button" value="EXP" onClick="exp_function()">
```

And I guess this will be working

```
function exp_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value = Math.exp(calc.display.value);
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: this one: `function sqrt_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value = Math.sqrt(calc.display.value);
}` works....but why do I have to change the previous `+= `sign to an `=` sign, and put `calc.display.value` within the brackets to make it work? Because for the others I didn't, and those work...? Also `calc.display.value+=1.442` doesn't work for the log function....the solution for the exponent problem works though.....everything works except for the log function!

Comment: In JS, a += b means a = a+b, so calc.display.value += Math.sqrt(); equals calc.display.value = calc.display.value + Math.sqrt(); and Math.sqrt() is NaN. What do you want is Math.sqrt(calc.display.value).

Comment: The other functions cos, sinus, etc.. don't work for me, you have to change them with the same method and it will be ok.